# How to fix "Cannot call value of non-function type `'Binding<() -> ()>'`"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am writing this function:

```swift
@ToolbarContentBuilder
func toolBarContent(displayMode: Binding<Bool>, showContents: Binding<Bool>) -> some ToolbarContent {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        HStack {
            Picker("Display Mode", selection: displayMode) {
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.portrait").tag(true)
                Image(systemName: "rectangle.split.2x1").tag(false)
            }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button {
            showContents.toggle()
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.fill")
        }
    }
}
```

On the following line:

```swift
showContents.toggle()
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<() -> ()>'
```

- What does that mean ?
- How can I define a function that returns `some ToolbarContent` and takes a `Binding<A>` parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `toggle` on a `Binding<Bool>` rather than on a `Bool`. You need to use `wrappedValue` to access the underlying value of a `Binding`.

So you need to replace `showContents.toggle()` with `showContents.wrappedValue.toggle()`.